# Angularjs vsGoogleAutocomplete plugin cannot detect change in controller

Tags: angularjs

I am writing a script which shows nearby ATMs. When page opens it auto detects user's location and if user wants to check ATMs in other areas he can type and choose other locations provided by google.

I am using this plugin: [vsAutoComplete](https://github.com/vskosp/vsGoogleAutocomplete). It's working fine, no issues. 
What I want to do is, when user chooses new location, script should list ATMs in that location.

I tried $watch

```
$scope.$watch('address', function () {
    console.log($scope.address);
}, true);
```

but that didn't work either. What's amazing is that if I try to access `address` variable in html page it works.

```
<span class="help-block"><b>Place id: </b>{{address.components.placeId}}</span>
```

Plugin Demo by developer : [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/sdcIaQ?p=preview)

Any clue ?

PS : I am not that good in angularjs.

Comment: Someone please answer...i am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Just giving my suggestion.. better approach will be this instead of assigning empty string, rest is upto you..

```
$scope.address = {
    name: null,
    place: null,
    components: {
      placeId: null,
      streetNumber: null, 
      street: null,
      city: null,
      state: null,
      countryCode: null,
      country: null,
      postCode: null,
      district: null,
      location: {
        lat: null,
        long: null
      }
    }
  };

  $scope.$watch('address.name', function (value) {
    if(value === null || value === undefined)
      return;
    else  
      console.log($scope.address.name);
  });

  //for deep watching
  $scope.$watch('address', function (value) {
    if(value === null || value === undefined)
      return;
    else  
      console.log($scope.address.name);
  }, true);
```

Comment: Appreciate your help @varsha, this is indeed a great suggestion.

Comment: Did you tried above solution..?? As you are looking for a object changes, there is one more watching approach that is to use $watchCollection. But it will not work for nested object as it performs only shallow watches elements/fields, and won’t react on changes to their subfields. Please have look into official documentation for different performance characteristics. [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

Comment: Yes i did try above solution as well, i had already tried $watchCollection as well. After lot of investigation i found that this problem exists with plugin itself so removed that plugin and used another plugin, and finally i got it working with $watch. I am sharing solution below.

Comment: Thank you very much for the kind help, and to keep me trying. My app will be live soon :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is what worked for me
I used some another plugin serving same purpose [google places autocomplete](https://github.com/kuhnza/angular-google-places-autocomplete), and then made few small changes

1) Add `ng-model` to input box

```
<input type="search" g-places-autocomplete ng-model="autolocation.model">
```

2) Initialize it in controller

```
$scope.autolocation = { 
  model: null
}
```

3) Add watch

```
$scope.$watch('autolocation.model', function(newValue, oldValue){
  console.log("New Location : " + angular.toJson(newValue, true));
});
```

4) Or this one

```
$scope.$on('g-places-autocomplete:select', function(event, place) {
   console.log("New Location: " + JSON.stringify(place));
});
```

yay, its done !